# Printing dictionary without brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm trying to write a script for an exercise that allows me to sort out the characters on a string and count the highest recurring characters but I can't seem to print out the results in a form of a string as its a tuple. Anyone has any idea on how I could do it would be much appreciated.

```
import sys

stringInput = (sys.argv[1]).lower()
stringInput = sorted(stringInput)
DictCount = {}
Dictionary = {}


def ListDict(tup, DictStr):
    DictStr = dict(tup)
    return DictStr


for chars in stringInput:
    if chars in Dictionary:
        Dictionary[chars] += 1
    else:
        Dictionary[chars] = 1

ListChar = sorted(Dictionary.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])

Characters = (ListChar[0], ListChar[1], ListChar[2], ListChar[3], ListChar[4])

print(ListDict(Characters, DictCount))
```

current output:

```
python3 CountPopularChars.py sdsERwweYxcxeewHJesddsdskjjkjrFGe21DS2145o9003gDDS
{'d': 7, 's': 7, 'e': 6, 'j': 4, 'w': 3}
```

desired output:

```
d:7,s:7,e:6,j:4,w:3
```

Comment: Please update your question with the current actual output, plus your desired output.

Comment: just loop and print items instead of trying to print the representation of the dictionary

Comment: Currently i tried to loop and print with     for i in range(5):
        print(*ListChar[i], sep=':', end=",") however its output has a ,% at the end

Comment: btw `DictCount` plays no part in your code and should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or just:

```
>>> dct = {'d': 7, 's': 7, 'e': 6, 'j': 4, 'w': 3}
>>> ','.join(f'{k}:{v}' for k,v in dct.items())
'd:7,s:7,e:6,j:4,w:3'
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked been stuck on this formatting thing for the longest time :)

Answer (score 3):

**create your output in this way:**

```
output = ','.join(f"{k}:{v}" for k, v in ListChar)
print(output)
```

**Output:**

> e:17,d:7,a:3,b:1,c:1

Comment: Hmm, ok, but you end up with a trailing `','`

Comment: sorry use this: `output = ','.join(f"{char}:{count}" for char, count in ListChar)`

Comment: @hmnFalahi this is not good edit answer and add `accept` anwer

Comment: yes i did edited my answer as you said @user1740577

Comment: @hmnFalahi everybody can see the old version of your answer in the revision panel

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
yourDict = {'d': 7, 's': 7, 'e': 6, 'j': 4, 'w': 3}
print(','.join("{}:{}".format(k, v) for k, v in yourDict.items()))
```

Output:

```
d:7,s:7,e:6,j:4,w:3
```

Comment: Hi this almost worked but the output i got has a spacing between ':' and the count.      d: 7, s: 7, e: 6, j: 4, w: 3

Comment: edited to remove the spacing

Comment: @TerenceChew: That's odd. I upvoted this answer precisely because the output was exactly as you required.

Comment: Thanks! no worries it helped me understand the way its done more

Answer (score 2):

Your code is highly redundant. You could write it in a much more concise way by using `collections.Counter` to help:

```py
from collections import Counter

# Hard coded stringInput for ease in this test
stringInput = 'sdsERwweYxcxeewHJesddsdskjjkjrFGe21DS2145o9003gDDS'.lower()

c = Counter(stringInput)

ListChar = sorted(c.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])

print(','.join(f"{k}:{v}" for k, v in ListChar[:5]))
```